# amCharts change width of each column (categoryAxis)

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Is there a way I can set the width of each column?? Here is a picture of what I have so far..

[image]

I have 12 points and I want to show all 12 numbers at the top and I want the lines to match the data points.. Ive tried every conceivable option and I cannot get it to work.. Is there something im missing?

my current config is..

```
{
  'type': 'serial',
  'categoryField': 'category',
  'columnWidth': '0.1',
  'plotAreaBorderColor': '#FFFFFF',
  'fontFamily': 'proxima-nova',
  'colors': [
    '#FFF'
  ],
  'startDuration': 1,
  'accessible': false,
  'addClassNames': true,
  'autoDisplay': true,
  'color': '#FFFFFF',
  'panEventsEnabled': false,
  'categoryAxis': {
    'gridPosition': 'start',
    'startOnAxis': true,
    "autoWrap": true,
    'position': 'top',
    'axisAlpha': 0,
    'axisThickness': 0,
    'color': '#FFFFFF',
    'gridColor': '#E5E5E5',
    'titleColor': '#FFFFFF'
  },
  'trendLines': [],
  'graphs': [
    {
      'balloonText': '[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]',
      'bullet': 'round',
      'id': 'AmGraph-1',
      'title': 'graph 1',
      'valueField': 'column-1'
    },
    {
      'balloonText': '[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]',
      'bullet': 'square',
      'id': 'AmGraph-2',
      'title': 'graph 2',
      'valueField': 'column-2'
    }
  ],
  'guides': [],
  'valueAxes': [
    {
      'id': 'ValueAxis-1',
      'axisAlpha': 0,
      'color': '#FFFFFF',
      'gridAlpha': 0.12
    }
  ],
  'allLabels': [],
  'balloon': {
    'enabled': false,
  },
  'dataProvider': [
    {
      'category': '1',
      'column-1': 8
    },
    {
      'category': '2',
      'column-1': 6
    },
    {
      'category': '3',
      'column-1': 2
    },
    {
      'category': '4',
      'column-1': 1
    },
    {
      'category': '5',
      'column-1': 2
    },
    {
      'category': '6',
      'column-1': 3
    },
    {
      'category': '7',
      'column-1': 6
    },
    {
      'category': '8',
      'column-1': 12
    },
    {
      'category': '9',
      'column-1': 13
    },
    {
      'category': '10',
      'column-1': 15
    },
    {
      'category': '11',
      'column-1': 17
    },
    {
      'category': '12',
      'column-1': 20
    }
  ]
}
```

now Ive tried.. setting the `widthField` to `category` but this happens..

[image]

I just want all the spaces to be even and show all the numbers at the top.. any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

for some reason if I set the `widthField` to something random I get what I want with the numbers and the lines like so..

[image]

but obviously that doesnt show the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [autoGridCount](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#autoGridCount) to `false` and change [gridCount](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#gridCount) to `12`. This offers an approximate number of grid columns which means it may not always show the exact number depending on different factors.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  'type': 'serial',
  'categoryField': 'category',
  'columnWidth': '0.1',
  'plotAreaBorderColor': '#FFFFFF',
  'fontFamily': 'proxima-nova',
  'colors': [
    '#FFF'
  ],
  'startDuration': 1,
  'accessible': false,
  'addClassNames': true,
  'autoDisplay': true,
  'color': '#FFFFFF',
  'panEventsEnabled': false,
  'categoryAxis': {
    'gridPosition': 'start',
    'startOnAxis': true,
    "autoWrap": true,
    'position': 'top',
    'axisAlpha': 0,
    'axisThickness': 0,
    'color': '#FFFFFF',
    'gridColor': '#E5E5E5',
    'titleColor': '#FFFFFF',
    'autoGridCount': false,
    'gridCount': 12
  },
  'trendLines': [],
  'graphs': [
    {
      'balloonText': '[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]',
      'bullet': 'round',
      'id': 'AmGraph-1',
      'title': 'graph 1',
      'valueField': 'column-1'
    },
    {
      'balloonText': '[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]',
      'bullet': 'square',
      'id': 'AmGraph-2',
      'title': 'graph 2',
      'valueField': 'column-2'
    }
  ],
  'guides': [],
  'valueAxes': [
    {
      'id': 'ValueAxis-1',
      'axisAlpha': 0,
      'color': '#FFFFFF',
      'gridAlpha': 0.12
    }
  ],
  'allLabels': [],
  'balloon': {
    'enabled': false,
  },
  'dataProvider': [
    {
      'category': '1',
      'column-1': 8
    },
    {
      'category': '2',
      'column-1': 6
    },
    {
      'category': '3',
      'column-1': 2
    },
    {
      'category': '4',
      'column-1': 1
    },
    {
      'category': '5',
      'column-1': 2
    },
    {
      'category': '6',
      'column-1': 3
    },
    {
      'category': '7',
      'column-1': 6
    },
    {
      'category': '8',
      'column-1': 12
    },
    {
      'category': '9',
      'column-1': 13
    },
    {
      'category': '10',
      'column-1': 15
    },
    {
      'category': '11',
      'column-1': 17
    },
    {
      'category': '12',
      'column-1': 20
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 font-size : 11px;
}

body {
  background-color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: YES! Thankyou this worked! Ive been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out!